# How to parse JsonResult object from controller in MVC?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am trying to learn asp.net. I am making a demo website in which there would be an admin panel. The admin would update the Daily Messages which will get reflected in the main homepage. I am using MVC.
I have created the table in database as

```
create table DailyMsg(Sno int primary key, msg varchar(max));
```

This is my controller

```
public class DailyMsgsController : Controller
    {
        private amenEntities db = new amenEntities();

        // GET: DailyMsgs
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Json(db.DailyMsgs.ToList(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

On running the following URL, I am successfully able to see the data in JSON format.

```
https://localhost:44329/DailyMsgs
```

```
[{"Sno":1,"msg":"Hi!"}]
```

Now, I am stuck. I know that I would have to add another class for Data Access Layer, but I am confused as how should I parse this data and print it to the main HTML page.

From my research on the internet, I have found out that I might have to use JQuery. So, I wrote the following(with what I could understand from the internet as I am not familiar with JQuery) -

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/DailyMsgs/Index",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#div1").html(data);    
    }
});
```

This, of course, is not working and I can't see anything on my webpage.

My Homepage.html

```
<body>
    <div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../JQuery/DailyMsgsJQ.js"></script>
```

All I want is to read and parse `msg` from JSON and display it on webpage.

Could you guide me as how should I proceed or is there any other way to achieve the purpose? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would start by opening a devtools in a browser and take a look at possible errors in the console and/or network tab. I am not very familiar with JQuery `ajax`, but I suspect the url is not right; I would try to either remove the leading slash (`url: "DailyMsgs/Index"`) or using the full url.

Comment: agree, check the request in the network tab because if it worked you would have at least the json-text get appended

Comment: @HynekS I am getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a 404()  :44374/favicon.ico:1

Comment: The favicon error just means you have no favicon (it's not related). Do you see the request for `DailyMsgs/Index` in the network tab? What about the console? Are there any errors?

Comment: No, the console doesn't show any other error. However, there isn't anything in the network tab. I guess, it isn't hitting the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/DailyMsgs/Index",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, element) {
            $("#div1").append(element.msg);    
        });
    }
});
```

If you still have error please get console.log(data); and send for me.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had a question. It updates the data very slow. Its like i have to wait for 3 seconds then it shows 'Hi'. Is there anyway I can make it load fast? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Load of the page depend to many item, there is nothing special that takes 3 seconds to load .

Comment: Use $("#div1").html(element.msg);  if you have one message to show.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<script>` tags are outside your `<html>` tag. That means the scripts are probably not even executed, or not loaded in the correct order. You want jQuery and Bootstrap to be loaded first, so put them in the `<head>`. Put your custom script just before the closing `</body>`, so it is loaded last.